# Sketch: disable snapping to layout rows while measuring distances

Tags: sketch-app, snapping

In Sketch, there is a measurement tool which works by selecting an object and dragging mouse towards other object while holding Alt key.

Is it possible to turn of it's snapping to Layout rows when Layout feature is turned on? It is especially confusing when you need to measure distance between two text blocks, which have invisible boundaries. Currently I have to turn off Layout when I want to avoid this snapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a [different variation of this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/104368/23864) last week, but the answer is the same:

[image: Command plus left clicking gets rid of snapping guides in Sketch]

<kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + `Left Click` gets rid of both the red guides and the snapping in Sketch.