# Sketch disable snap to automatic guidelines

Tags: sketch-app

How can I disable snapping of a cursor to the red guidelines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Command plus left clicking gets rid of snapping guides in Sketch]

<kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd> + `Left Click` gets rid of both the red guides and the snapping in Sketch.

Answer (score 2):

Hide the guidelines and the cursor shouldn't snap anymore.

[image: untick show layout to hide the lines]

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide all guidelines which effectively disables (or enables) snapping

[image]